# Problems creating a Template Queue

Tags: c++, templates, queue

I am attempting to write my own template queue class to learn how to use templates. I see that this type of question is asked often, and I have read many of the responses but I still do not see what I am doing wrong.

```
template <class type>
struct Node{
    type data;
    Node *next;
};

template <class type>
class LinkedListQueue{
public:
    LinkedListQueue();
    void push(type new_data);
    void pop();
    type front();
    void print();

private:
    Node<type> *head;
    Node<type> *tail;
};

template <class type>
LinkedListQueue<type>::LinkedListQueue(){
    this->head = NULL;
    this->tail = NULL;
}

template <class type>
void LinkedListQueue<type>::push(type new_data){
    Node<type> *newNode;
    newNode->data = new_data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(this->head == NULL){
        this->head = newNode;
        this->tail = newNode;
    }else{
        this->tail->next = newNode;
        this->tail = newNode;
    }
}

template <class type>
void LinkedListQueue<type>::pop(){
    if(this->head != NULL){
        this->head = this->head->next;
        if(this->head == NULL){
            this->tail == NULL;
        }
    }else{
    cout << "Queue is Empty" << endl;
    }
}

template <class type>
type LinkedListQueue<type>::front(){
    return(this->head->data);
}

int main() {
    LinkedListQueue<int> newQueue;
    newQueue.push(5);
    newQueue.push(4);
    cout << newQueue.front() << endl;
    newQueue.pop();
    cout << newQueue.front() << endl;
}
```

I am having trouble determining where the problem is. If I comment off the pop and last front call, the first front() call outputs correctly. However, uncommenting pop and front breaks everything. When I try to debug pop() it seems like there is only one Node in the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try using a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allocating your new node. just storing the data.

```
Node<type> *newNode; //<=== indeterminate pointer
newNode->data = new_data;
newNode->next = NULL;
```

One way or another, you're always pushing a new element in, so allocate it, set it up, then figure out where it goes. Also, create a constructor for your node that takes a const-ref of the data, and sets the next to NULL. This makes your code significantly more straight-forward (and actually more efficient):

```
Node<type> *newNode = new Node<type>(new_data);
```

With the Node template becoming:

```
template <class type>
struct Node
{
    Node(const type& value) 
        : data(value), next(NULL) {};
    type data;
    Node *next;
};
```

Finally, your `pop()` isn't deleting the node, just mucking with the pointers. you may want to address that as well.

```
template <class type>
void LinkedListQueue<type>::pop()
{
    if(this->head != NULL)
    {
        Node<type>* victim = this->head;
        this->head = this->head->next;
        if(this->head == NULL)
            this->tail == NULL;
        delete victim; // <=== note: deleting node.
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Queue is Empty" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2017001 how I wish that were true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **big** problem:

```
Node<type> *newNode;
newNode->data = new_data;
```

You declare a pointer and start accessing it directly, without allocating memory for it. This means the pointer points to a seemingly random location. leading to *undefined behavior* and weird things happening has to be expected.

Also, if you allocate memory for the node, you have a memory leak as you don't free the nodes in the `pop` function.